# How to connect multiple sensors to TXD and RXD pins of Raspberry Pi?

Tags: serial, sensor, raspberry-pi-os

I want to connect multiple lidar distance sensors to my Raspberry Pi. (Like the picture below)

[image: Four lidar sensors]

The lidar distance measurement sensor has 5v, TXD, RXD and GND pins.
When I looked, it seemed that the TXD and RXD pins of the Raspberry Pi communicate with the sensor one-to-one.

(If multiple connections are connected, the Raspberry Pi turns off.)

If I try to connect 5 sensors to 1 Raspberry Pi, how do I connect TXD and RXD?

Answer (score 1):

You can not connect multiple serial devices to an interface (although it may be possible with additional circuitry to multiplex devices - only one can work at a time).

You can of course SEND to multiple devices but only receive from one.

Comment: **(although it may be possible with additional circuitry to multiplex devices)**
Okay.... then.. how can I get information about a multi-connected circuit?

Comment: I only add this disclaimer to discourage pedants. You will need to design software and hardware to communicate with one at a time. This is a EE question not Pi specific and depends on the devices you are interfacing.

Comment: 5x serial to usb converters and a usb hub?

Comment: I would do a search for *multiple serial port hat for Raspberry Pi* These hats come in up to eight ports (maybe more since I was involved in serial comms). Often they are using the SC16IS752 chip in I2C mode (SPI possible) for two ports and extra I/O pins

Comment: Oh one other point - check voltages - RS/232 and serial are very abused terms and the voltages can range from +12v with -12v, via 5v with 0v to 3.3v with 0v and still be called serial...